# How to say "I don't want you to be sad" in Taiwanese Mandarin?

Tags: translation, taiwan

Let's use 難過 to translate "sad", then, in Mandarin as spoken in Taiwan, what would be the most common way to say:

> I don't want you to be sad.

As you might say when you notice that someone is sad who you would like to be happy instead.

Comment: 嫑難過啊。。。。。。。。。。。

Comment: 我不想你難過。 ........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "I don't want you to be sad."

We say 別難過了 in Taiwan. The most common one.

我們說「別難過了」。這是最常用的講法。